# Symfony @Security Annotation with a custom Voter

Tags: php, security, symfony, annotations

I've written a custom voter to check if a user is the owner of a book, that he's trying to edit.
Therefore i'm using the "@Security" annotation to secure the Controller:

```
@Security("is_granted('BookVoter::ATTRIBUTE_OWNER', book)")
```

This is what I would like to have the @Security annotation look like, but it is only working when I write the following:

```
@Security("is_granted('OWNER', book)")
```

I don't want to "hardcode" the 'OWNER' string, it is a constant within my BookVoter.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you pass to the `@Security` annotation is [Expression Language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/index.html).

The SensionFrameworkExtraBundle provide the `is_granted` function to the expression language ([see here](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Security/ExpressionLanguage.php)).

Expression Language has by default a `constant()` function, so you should use it in your case:

```
@Security("is_granted(constant('\\Full\\Namespace\\To\\BookVoter::ATTRIBUTE_OWNER'), book)")
```

Note that you should use the full namespace notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I got home and tried your approach, can't find the constant either. I installed expression language with composer .. Hm any other idea how to pass the constant within the "is_granted" ?

Comment: Ok, here is the deal: You must use '\\" double backslashes for specifying the constant value.